# Using result of intermediate insert in transaction with Ecto

Tags: transactions, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Using Ecto v2.2.6, Phoenix 1.3

I have a blog app.  When a user makes a Post, it inserts into the `Post` table, then it get the resulting id of that post and inserts that into a `Newsfeeditem` table.  Ideally, I would like for this to happen as a transaction.

(I am using Absinthe graphql, so my return for the insert must be of the form `{:ok, post}`)

I have a working function that looks like this:

```
  def create_post_add_newsfeed(%{
      title: title,
      content: content,
      user_id: user_id
    }) do

    case Repo.insert!(%Post{title: title, content: content, user_id: user_id}) do
      post ->
        case Repo.insert!(%Newsfeeditem{type: "user_creates_post", user_id: user_id, post_id: post.id}) do
          newsfeeditem ->
            {:ok, post}
          _ ->
            {:error, "Post not recorded in newsfeed"}
        end
      _ ->
      {:error, "Post not inserted"}
    end
  end
```

This code is not a transaction, and it reeks of callback stink.  Ecto.Multi seems like a more appropriate tool to use here, but I do not know how to get the result of the `Post` insert so that I can insert it into `Newsfeed`.

I would like to do something like this

```
  def create_post_add_newsfeed(%{
      title: title,
      content: content,
      user_id: user_id
    }) do
    multi =
      Multi.new
        |> Multi.insert(:post, %Post{title: title, content: content, user_id: user_id})
        |> # Some intermediate step where I get the 'post' from the line above
        |> Multi.insert(:newsfeeditem, %Newsfeeditem{type: "user_creates_post", user_id: users_id, post_id: post.id})

    case Repo.transaction(multi) do
      {:ok, %{post: post}} ->
        {:ok, post}
      {:error, _} ->
        {:error, "Error"}
    end
  end
```

Any idea how to pull that off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Multi.run/3` for this. The function passed to `Multi.run/3` will receive the changes so far as the argument. You can extract the inserted `post` from that and issue a `Repo.insert` for the `Newsfeeditem` inside `Multi.run`. The function should return `{:ok, _}` or `{:error, _}` which is exactly what `Repo.insert` returns so you don't need to do anything more inside the function.

```
Multi.new
|> Multi.insert(:post, %Post{title: title, content: content, user_id: user_id})
|> Multi.run(:newsfeeditem, fn %{post: post} ->
  Repo.insert(%Newsfeeditem{type: "user_creates_post", user_id: users_id, post_id: post.id})
end)
```